# How can I disable the Windows Error Reporting prompt but still collect a crash dump?

Tags: windows, crash, windows-7, crash-dumps

I have Windows Error Reporting configured to collect a crash dump when a particular (Win32 C++) application crashes using the registry settings recommended [at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps?redirectedfrom=MSDN). On crash, the process stays on the screen with a "MyProgram.exe has stopped working" prompt. A monitoring process automatically restarts the crashed process, and the dialog prevents that from happening.

Is there any way to bypass this prompt while still collecting a crash dump?

Ideally, I would prefer to not modify the running binary.

Comment: [SetErrorMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-seterrormode).

Comment: SetErrorMode looks like a good approach if you can easily modify the software. Is there any way to change this setting without modifying the binary? If not, is there at least a way to check the current error mode of a running process?

Comment: use [procdump to generate dumps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump#examples)

Comment: In addition to disabling WER? That seems like a good solution, I'll give it a shot. Thanks!